# How can I encode text data as features for ML algorithms in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have a csv file which have columns filled with text data. How can I replace them with constant data so I can apply machine learning algorithm on that dataset. 
Dataset Example: Date, Name, Color Name, User Name and Product Name.

Comment: You need to describe your data properly and what you want to do with that.

Comment: I have color name how can I replace them and I have User Name

Comment: There are too many options and you need to choose the best for your data.
Things you might do:  
1. create list of unique word, give each one of them id and replace each word in the dataset with its id.  
2. use word embedding layer..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to categorize your data. Try the following:

Example 1: For the color name and product name assuming there are only a few types, you can map as follows:

```
# Color_name mapping
color_mapping = {"red": 1, "yellow": 2, "blue": 3, "green": 4, "pink": 5}
dataset['color_name'] = dataset['color_name'].map(color_mapping)
# Product_name mapping
product_mapping = {"product1": 1, "product2": 2, "product3": 3, "product4": 4, "product5": 5}
dataset['product_name'] = dataset['product_name'].map(product_mapping)
```

Example 2: For user_name if they cannot be categorized as above, you can do the following:

Try extracting titles from the name.

Ex: Names starting with titles Mr., Ms., Mrs. etc can be extracted and can be grouped accordingly

```
title_mapping = {"Mr": 1, "Miss": 2, "Mrs": 3}
dataset['user_name'] = dataset['user_name'].map(title_mapping)
```

Example 3: For date, you can group them as dates belonging to different years or months or for some particular period etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the upper answers and comments just explain half of the work. 
1, 2, 3, ... imply spacial dependencies within the encoded words, e.g. "red" is closer to "yellow" than to "blue", since 1 is closer to 2 than to 3.
After applying a transformation to integer values you should go for something like a [one-hot-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot).

If you use pandas check out [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

If you use sklearn go for [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html)

[(Here you can find a very good tutorial on how to deal with categorical data)](http://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html)

Since a one-hot-encoding blows up your actual data you feed into the network you might consider using dimensionalty reduction techniques upfront or maybe the best way is to use so called [word embeddings](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/). Today it's very advisable to use word embeddings in real text data, since they were a game changer for modern NLP applications. If you're only dealing with single words there is no need for word embeddings.

Cheers